# Как реализовать переход в новый день в данной задачке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Данная программа принимает 3 значения H, A, B , где H - время в часовом поясе человека, A - В каком часовом поясе живет человек, B - В каком часовом поясе живет другой человек.
Нужно, чтобы при выводе время другого человека выводилось число от 0 до 23. В проверках и вычислениях программа сначала узнает часовой пояс UTC + 0, а далее время у другого человека, нужно сделать переход в новый день.

```
    print("Введите время в часовом поясе человека")
    H = int(input())
    print("В каком часовом поясе живет человек")
    A = int(input())
    print("В каком часовом поясе живет другой человек")
    B = int(input())

    if A > 0 and B < 0 :
        answer = H - A + B     
    if A < 0 and B < 0 :
        answer = H + A - B
    if A < 0 and B > 0 :
        answer = H - A + B
    if A > 0 and B > 0 :
        answer = H - A + B

    print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
h = int(input("Введите время в часовом поясе человека\n"))
a = int(input("В каком часовом поясе живет человек\n"))
b = int(input("В каком часовом поясе живет другой человек\n"))

c = b - a
h += c

if h > 23:
    h -= 24
if h < 0:
    h += 24

print(h)
```